# Best way to create empty json for typescript, or should I init with null?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

Pretty simple question that I already have a solution for but it looks ugly to me.

I am trying to access local storage but I need to useEffect and if I want to extract the value from inside useEffect I need to instantiate before the codeblock in the higher scope.

Typescript does not accept `var temp:JSON = {}` So I have to do the cumbersome `var temp:JSON = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({}))` which works.  But it seems somewhat stupid to me that Javascript will randomly coerce my string into truthy values with == but can't coerce an empty Object into JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JSON` type is probably not what you need to be using for this. This type reflects an interface for converting data to/from JSON, aka the JSON global object in JavaScript.

Instead, you should create an interface that reflects the type of data stored in localstorage, then use that interface as the type for the parsed string from localstorage:

```
interface StoredObject {
  name?: string;
  kind?: string;
  ...
}

...

const [storedObject, setStoredObject] = useState<StoredObject>();

useEffect(() => {
  const jsonString = localStorage.getItem(key);
  setStoredObject(JSON.parse(jsonString));
}, []);
```

Comment: I like your solution but I am lazy and don't want to define an interface for something like this.  Instead I can just do like you did and use `const jsonString:string` and then setString. (I also realized unrelatedly that I need to do something else to confirm that it is clientside code so I'm no longer using react hooks) ```let userString:string = ''
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    userString = localStorage.getItem('user');
}```

Comment: Also sorry for trash formatting in the above comment but since stack overflow thinks it knows how best to use carriage return (immediately submitting a response) I'm not going to bother adding in newlines to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work like this:

```
const temp:JSON = {} as JSON;
```

However, you should consider why TypeScript returns an error:

> error TS2739: Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'JSON': parse, stringify, [Symbol.toStringTag]

The type `JSON` is meant for the built-in `JSON` object and not for its output. In your case, `temp` is just a regular `Object`.

Answer (score -1):

you can do like this:

```js
let foo:JSON = {} as JSON;
```

I hope it help you.